# How to hide the previously loaded ajax content, using toggle function

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is how my pagination script works

1: on page load - ajax load content automatically (done)

2: onClick load_more btn(using toggle show) - load and show more content (done)

3: onClick load_more btn(using toogle hide) - hide whatever was loaded at set 2 (how to implement this)

```
<div class="resultsblock">

    <div class="results"></div>

    <div class="clear:left;"></div>

   <button class="load_more" id="load_more_button"></button>
   <div class="animation_image" style="display:block;">Loading...</div>

</div>

<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
    var url = "http://www.abc.com";

    var track_click = 1; //track user click on "load more" button

    var total_pages = <?php echo $this->totalPages(); ?>;
    console.log(total_pages);
    // default load 
    jQuery('.results').load(url, {'p':track_click}, function() 
    {


    jQuery('.animation_image').hide();

    if(total_pages==1) {  jQuery(".load_more").hide();  } else { jQuery(".load_more").show();    }

    }
); 

    jQuery(".load_more").toggle(function(){

    jQuery(this).hide();                  
        jQuery('.animation_image').show(); 
            console.log(track_click);    
            // ajax load first load
            jQuery.post(url,{'p': track_click}, function(data) {            
                jQuery(".load_more").show();                 
                jQuery(".results").append(data);               
                jQuery('.animation_image').hide();                  
            });        

        // Now how to hide the elements loaded by ajax 

    },function(){console.log('hide previous load')});   --- step 3      
});

// this may not affect toggle. It just waiting for ajax to finish and perform more..

jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
if(jQuery('.prod').length != 0) {
    jQuery(".prod").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_title").hide();
    jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").fadeIn();
},function(){        
jQuery(this).find(".prod_desc").fadeOut(); 

jQuery(this).find(".prod_title_wrap").show();
jQuery(this).find(".prod_title").show();

    });
}

});



</script>
```

I don't want to hide the first content which is showing on page load in starting. How can I achieve this please suggest something. Thank you

Comment: F.Y.I. [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that could do:

```
...
jQuery(".load_more").show();                   
jQuery(".results").fadeOut(function() {
    jQuery(".results")
        .empty()
        .append(data)
        .fadeIn()
    ;
});
...
```

Comment: It's kinda stuck at empty and then it appends. Is it possible to just hide the previously loaded content? instead of emptying the whole .results div and then append again?

Comment: Thanks for that but I do not want to empty the whole .result element . Because on page load content loads automatically and I am trying to implement toggle after that. So don't want to touch the initial load. But upon emptying .results it's even hiding the initial load as well and yes populating again but it does not look nice.

Comment: Is there any way we can keep track of what was loaded in the last ajax call?

Comment: you can always wrap it with any div, and then empty it